# Why case class is named 'case'?

Tags: scala, case-class

`Case is '*an instance of a particular situation; an example of something occurring*'.

So my question is - why Scala 'case' classes are named as 'case'? What is the point? Why it is 'case', not 'data' class or something else? What does mean 'case' in that.. case :)

Comment: I guess mainly because they can be used as patterns in _pattern matching_  expressions, e.g. `myVal match { case MyCaseClass(a, b) => ... }`, where each case class is a separate _case_...

Comment: To whoever voted for close: I don't think this question is too broad.

Comment: Obviously, a case class is just a container of data fields, the way a suitcase is a container of suits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The primary use of the `case` keyword in other languages is in `switch`-statements which are mostly used on `enum`s or comparable values such as `int`s or `string`s being used to represent different well-defined cases:

```
switch (value)
{ 
   case 1: // do x -
   case 2: // do y - 
   default: // optional
}
```

In Scala these classes often represent the specific well-defined possible instances of an abstract class and are used in much the same way imperative code uses switch-statements within `match`-clauses:

```
value match {
    case Expr(lhs, rhs) => // do x
    case Atomic(a) => // do y
    case _ => // optional, but will throw exception if something cannot be matched whereas switch won't
}
```

Much of the behavior of case classes such as the way they can be constructed aims at facilitating/enabling their use in such statements.

Comment: The similarity to Java makes it hard for me now to get a Java switch right the first time. I wish the keyword were different, perhaps reusing `match` (which they say started life as a method name). Since the cases are just patterns, `{ match p1 => }`. Possibly that would be unambiguous and also save a keyword. Why didn't they do that? (Inferring NL might be tricky, `{ match p1 => x match etc }`.)

Answer (score 1):

It's because they can be used for pattern matching. A *case* in English usage means *one of the possibilities*; and that's what pattern matching works out for you.

e.g., "There are three cases we must consider here..."

Comment: They don't "work via" pattern matching, but can be used in pattern matching. The last sentence of midor's answer is a much better formulation.